# Autocorrelation test on hierarchical data turns insignificant?

Tags: r, autocorrelation, durbin-watson-test

I am running tests to show how multilevel modelling is superior to fixed effects when it comes to hierarchical data structures (clustered data: years and countries). I am using the dwtest (lmtest-package) to measure autocorrelation and theoretically the autocorrelation should be considerably higher if country-specific variables (e.g. election systems) are added. However, this does not seem to be the case - the dwtest turns insignificant when election system variables are added to the fixed effects model. How can this be explained? Here are my codes and output.

fixed effects with individual variables (e.g. gender, age, income)

```
fix.multi <- lm(efficacy~uddannelse+kvinde+alder+husindkomst+hojre.venstre+sektor+arbejdslos+religios+land.by+polviden+factor(land)+factor(aar), data=OLS)
```

> dwtest(fix.multi)

```
Durbin-Watson test

data:  fix.multi
DW = 1.8747, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0
```

fixed effects with country variables (e.g. election systems)

```
fix.mld <-lm(efficacy~valgsystem+spaerre+valgreg+kamre+uddannelse+kvinde+alder+husindkomst+hojre.venstre+sektor+arbejdslos+religios+land.by+polviden+factor(land), data=MLM)

dwtest(fix.mld)

Durbin-Watson test

data:  fix.mld
DW = 1.8925, p-value = 0.7692
alternative hypothesis: true autocorrelation is greater than 0
```

Comment: can you give a little more justification for your premise "theoretically the autocorrelation should be considerably higher if country-specific variables (e.g. election systems) are added"?  It's not immediately obvious to me why this should be true

Comment: Because the individual observations are correlated when it comes to group variables, e.g. election systems. For instance, all people living in France are subject to the same electoral system.

Comment: but *correlation* is not the same as *autocorrelation*.  Is there any chance we can have a reproducible example?